One step in Azure SQL job does not retry
I have an Azure SQL Database with a weekly maintenance job. The job scales the database up, performs various tasks, potentially including an index rebuild if fragmentation is high, and then scales the database down again.
My issue is that, even though the 'scale-down' step of the job has 10 retries and a timeout of 12 hours configured, the step fails after 52 seconds, and doesn't retry.
The step definition:

An example execution:

It's a generic error, which is fine and expected:

Command failed: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.  A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

All other steps complete successfully - the 'scale-up' operation actually did need to retry before it succeeded, which is encouraging:

The error is the same as in the step which does not retry.
If you have any insight into why a certain step would not retry, when others in the same job do, then I'd really appreciate it - the same issue seems to occur in every execution of the job!
EDIT: It looks like markdown tables aren't supported here, swapped them out for screenshots.

Are you using Azure Elastic Jobs or Azure Automation to create the jobs?

@AlbertoMorillo It's Azure Elastic Jobs

I cannot help you. I use Azure Automation Jobs and I have never had any issues. No need to retry. I have customers scaling up early in the morning and scaling down in the evening with no issues for more than 6 years using Azure Automation. Let me know if you want me to give you an example using PowerShell on an Azure Automation job.
